# Meaning of Ynaqdhm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I accidentally created a rails app that already exists (i.e. `rails new existingapp`)

The terminal says

> Overwrite /Users/username/Desktop/existingapp/.gitignore? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm]

What does Ynaqdhm stand for? I guess they are the available options? (e.g. y: yes, n: no ?) I pressed `a` thinking it would mean abort, but the new app went ahead, so perhaps it meant all. Where can I find what this means

Comment: It might list all the commands if you type "h". Ya, it seems like a list of commands; especially since it starts with "yn".

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks. I will try to get the error again to see. Do you know if it's a rails or a OS wide thing?

Comment: No clue, I don't use Rails.

Comment: It's a Rails thing, but the convention is pretty widely used in CLI interfaces. Use "h" to get a description of the available options. The uppercase "Y" indicates this is the default option if you just push "enter".

Comment: I ran it again and a means `a - all, overwrite this and all others`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Y - yes, overwrite
n - no, do not overwrite
a - all, overwrite this and all others
q - quit, abort
d - diff, show the differences between the old and the new
h - help, show this help
m - merge, run merge tool
```